# django form __init__ not including fields

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms, django-admin

I have made a custom action for the admin page of one of my models wherein permissions can be granted to all the selected objects. There is an intermediate page which shows a multichoice field of the users to whom the permissions are to be granted.

The entire action, start to finish, was working fine unless I ran into some (unrelated) issues with 'south'. As a fix, I had to include `__init__` in the forms declaration. Now however, the users and selected objects in the intermediate stream load correctly but the form is not validating once the 'Okay' button is clicked.

From what I have debugged, when I use `if request.POST.get('post'):`, it doesn't send a POST back once OK is clicked. When I use `if request.method == 'POST':`, it sends a POST while displaying the form but when OK is clicked, the form fails the `is_valid()` test because fields are missing.

The same code worked flawlessly when I didn't use `__init__`

```
from models import ClientInfo
from customauth.models import ZenatixUser


class SelectUserForm(forms.Form):
    _selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)

    def __init__(self, initial, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SelectUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            clientObj = ClientInfo.objects.all()[:1].get()
            client = clientObj.corp
            client_name = client.shortName
            client_id = client.cID
            userList = ZenatixUser.objects.filter(corp__cID=client_id)
            #user = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(userList, label=client_name + ' users ')
            self.fields['user'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(userList, label=client_name + ' users ')
            self._selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)
        except ClientInfo.DoesNotExist:
            raise Exception('Please add a client info object to the client')


def grant_read_permission(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    opts = modeladmin.model._meta
    app_label = opts.app_label

    form = None

    #if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST.get('post'):
        print 'POST'
        form = SelectUserForm(request.POST)
        print form.errors

        if form.is_valid():
            print 'Valid'
            users = form.cleaned_data['user']
            stream_count = queryset.count()
            user_count = len(users)
            for stream in queryset:
                for user in users:
                    print user, stream
                    assign_perm('read_stream', user, stream)

            plural = ['', '']
            if user_count != 1:
                plural[0] = 's'
            if stream_count != 1:
                plural[1] = 's'

            modeladmin.message_user(request, "Successfully granted read permission to %d user%s on %d stream%s." % (
                user_count, plural[0], stream_count, plural[1]))

            return None

    if not form:
        form = SelectUserForm(initial={'_selected_action': request.POST.getlist(admin.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)})

    if len(queryset) == 1:
        objects_name = force_unicode(opts.verbose_name)
    else:
        objects_name = force_unicode(opts.verbose_name_plural)

    stream_list = []
    for stream in queryset:
        stream_list.append(stream.path)

    title = _("Are you sure?")

    context = {
        "title": title,
        "objects_name": objects_name,
        'queryset': stream_list,
        "opts": opts,
        "app_label": app_label,
        'action_checkbox_name': helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME,
        'tag_form': form,
    }

    return render_to_response("admin/grant_read_permission.html", context,
                              context_instance=template.RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've extracted one argument, which you've called initial, from the args/kwargs lists, and you're not passing it to the super call. Actually, the first positional argument is the form data, and without it the form will never be valid. Remove that name from the method definition.

Comment: So it works now, thanks a lot for that! :)
But could be explain how exactly is the `initial` variable being used to set the value of `_selected_action`? I also removed the `self._selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)` line and it still works.
Confused. o.O